# How to indicate a long integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following error in my Python code:

```
File "number.py", line 4
    print("Absolute value: "+str(abs(119L)))
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the cause?

Comment: What's the `L` there for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to indicate long types as one might with C-type languages. [Python 3.0 integers are always as big as necessary](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers), so just drop the `L`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you don't need to worry with long integers. You only need to declare an integer and forget the memory allocation and if the integer will be short or long.